# How do you use Scheme in OS X?

Tags: macos, scheme

I downloaded scheme from http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/

I now have some sketchy X11 window...[image: window]

and now I have no idea what to do...  Shouldn't this have returned 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `M-z` evaluates the definition that point is in

…according to [TFM](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Edwin-Scheme-Evaluation.html#Edwin-Scheme-Evaluation). That means Meta-Z, which usually means Alt-Z.

Answer (score 10):

Give [Racket](http://racket-lang.org) a try. It's very user-friendly, has a nice GUI and runs fine in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Xcode installed, you may find it easier to build and use this or a different Scheme from the command line (the Terminal app). Try [Chibi](http://code.google.com/p/chibi-scheme/) or [Gambit](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).